# How to change sudo passwords

Tags: password, sudo, administrator

When I try to change a sudo password, it say it doesn't work even running the 
mount -rw -o remount /
When you run that command it would say i worked from the root menu but would still be invalid when you logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. All you have to do is run the following commands.
mount -rw -o remount /
sudo administrator passwd
then it will prompt you for the new password and it will say changed but it will actually work this time.